# why is it legal to declare an inbuilt library function as an identifier name?

Tags: c

This is the  declaration of a variable printf:

```
int printf=90;
```

This runs without any error , but if I try to print the value of the identifier with the given name printf , then it gives error , so why is it that although the compiler is allowing  printf to be used as an identifier but we can't later print its value .

Comment: So you can pass them as pointers, to other functions...

Comment: Because it is not "inbuilt". It is just in a library supplied by a compiler as courtesy..

Comment: @Shark No, that doesn't make any sense and is not what's happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is a bit mixed up.

C has "scope rules", that govern how a name (like `printf`) is resolved from a given point in the code. It's possible, and legal according to the scope rules, to *shadow* a name from an outer scope.

Typically `printf` is `extern`-declared from `<stdio.h>`, and its value is replaced by the proper function address from the standard library by the linker.

But if you declare a new variable like that, you are shadowing the name. Basically you get a new variable of a new type, with the same name as an existing one. The outer, original, `printf` then becomes unreachable from that scope, since C doesn't have a scope resolution operator. In C++, you could use `::printf` which always references the global `printf`. C doesn't have that.

You can work around it by copying the original value of `printf` before shadowing it:

```
{
  int (*theprintf)(const char *fmt, ...) = printf;
  int printf = 90;
  theprintf("now printf has the value %d\n", printf);
}
```

As mentioned in a comment, once you're done with your local variant you can re-declare it as `extern` to get it back, but you can't do that *in the same scope*:

```
{
  extern int printf(const char * fmt, ...);
  printf("hello?\n");
}
```

Comment: You can make the outer printf visible again by declaring it in the scope where you want to make it visible. Just write `extern int printf(const char*, ...);` and voilà! It's visible again.

Comment: You're right, your explanation is much detailed and better than mine was, nice one (y). I approached the shadowing part from a... very wrong way I suppose.